# Linux permissions varies between parent directory and double dots

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, redhat-enterprise-linux, ls

I have a directory content:

```
[root@myserver ~]# ll -a /home/user/.ssh
drwx------.  2 thomas water   48 26 nov.  15:57 .
drwxrwxrwx. 12 thomas water 4096 25 nov.  11:36 ..
-rwx------.  1 thomas water 1960 26 nov.  15:55 authorized_keys
-rwx------.  1 thomas water  183 29 janv.  2021 known_hosts
```

I notice that the parent directory is showing a total access with drwxrwxrwx.

When I look at the parent directory itself, I get different permissions:

```
[root@myserver ~]# ll -a /home/user | grep ssh
drwx------. 2 thomas water    29 29 nov.  11:38 .ssh
```

I don't explain such a difference.

The actual permissions are those shown on the directory itself, not on the `..` link.

I'm actually having troubles with SSH connections *via* key pairs and I'm wondering if it could be related to this. When I `ssh thomas@myserver`, I'm not prompted for passphrase for my key. I'm basically prompted for user's password, as if no SSH key was configured. I'm not having the problem for SSH connections with other users on the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `..` hard link corresponds to `/home/user`, not `/home/user/.ssh`.

It's the `.` that corresponds to `/home/user/.ssh`, and you can see that their permissions are the same.